# Excel stacked bar chart not plotted correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stacked-chart, axlsx, excel-charts

I am using [Axlsx gem](https://github.com/randym/axlsx) for generating the excel charts on ruby on rails. My requirement is to generate a **stacked bar chart** but it is generating in a staircase format [refer the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sCGY.png). To generate the chart I have used the following code,

```
sheet.add_chart(Axlsx::BarChart, start_at: "B5", end_at: "I20", title: "Test Title", grouping: :stacked) do |chart|
    chart.barDir = :col
    chart.add_series(data: sheet["C3:E3"], labels: sheet["C2:E2"], title: sheet["C1"])
    chart.add_series(data: sheet["F3:H3"], labels: sheet["C2:E2"], title: sheet["F1"])
  end
```

When I manually edit the generated chart in Microsoft Excel and set `Series Overlap` to 100%, I'm getting the desired output [refer the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyNgL.png).